# Issue on Overleaf: "LaTeX Error: File `cgloss.sty' not found"

Tags: overleaf, compilation-error

I see a lot of people have asked questions about .cls files not loading properly -- but so far as I see none of them are about how to manage this on Overleaf.

I have a file that compiles just fine in TexStudio, but when I zip it and put it on Overleaf, I get the error in the subject line above. I don't know how to fix this. Can someone give me some advice? Forgive my stupidity!

```
\documentclass[]{article}
 \def\bibitem{%
    \vskip\baselineskip% % space above
    \noindent%           % suppress regular indent
    \hangindent=1.5em%   % indent same amount as `quotation` environment
}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{cgloss4e}
\usepackage{phonrule}
\usepackage{gb4e, cgloss}
\def\Id#1{\vskip-.32cm\hskip.01cm\vtop{#1}}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\setcitestyle{notesep={: }}
\setcitestyle{aysep={}}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumerate}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate
\usepackage[labelsep=space]{caption}
%\stepcounter{section} % So that the labels have different values
%\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{times}
 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage{titlesec}
 \setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
 \titleformat{\paragraph}
 {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
 \titlespacing*{\paragraph}
 {0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
 
 %\linenumbers
 
%opening
\title{Please help me}
%\author{Me}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
My god why won't this compile in Overleaf. Sometimes I feel so stupid.

\bibliography{bibliowhat}

\bibliographystyle{apalikefull.bst}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I too feel stupid since a few years @Teusz. Hang in there and it will get better hopefully.

Answer (score 4):

I just uploaded the style file `cgloss.sty` from

https://github.com/langsci/guidelines/blob/master/latexguidelines/cgloss.sty

to the directory containing your tex file. They complied perfectly at Overleaf and generated the following picture.
[image]

Comment: The original source for `cgloss.sty` is here: https://staticweb.hum.uu.nl/medewerkers/alexis.dimitriadis/latex/. Unfortunately Alexis hasn't ever put it on CTAN.